# How to install JavaFx on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

I downloaded the JavaFx preview from oracle home page. It's  a zip file, I wonder how one could install it on Ubuntu 12.04 pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the installation instructions on the JavaFX 2 release notes for Linux.
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/release_notes_linux/jfxpub-release_notes_linux.htm

To install: 
Download the JavaFX SDK zip file from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Extract the SDK files from the zip file to a directory on your local file system.

There is more detailed info in these blog posts if you need it.

http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2012/01/26/javafx_2_1_sdk_developer_preview_comes_to_linux.html

http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2012/02/03/running_32_bit_javafx_2_1_beta_sdk_on_64_bit_ubuntu_11_10.html

The blog posts also mention how to ensure that the correct codecs for media playback are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it simpler to install a plain Oracle non-GPL Java 1.8 JDK on Ubuntu, JavaFX is included there and works automagically.